# Separation in nodes in diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, forest

I have this nodes diagram.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        draw
    }
    [A
       [B
       [E]
       ]

       [C
       [H]
       ]
    ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

It produce this:

[image]

But I want separations like a triangle. Like this:

[image]

How can I do it? Any idea?

Thanks for help me :)

Comment: Could you please remove the empty line in the code as it generates an error? (+1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know the solution utilizing the `forest`-library. However, instead of `forest`-library, one can simply use the `positioning`-library to achieve the desired effect. The code follows...

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\def\X{.5}
\def\Y{1.5}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
    every node/.style={circle,draw}
    ]
%
% the LHS branch
\node (A) at (0,0) {A};
\node[below left=\Y cm and \X cm of A] (B) {B};
\node[below left=\Y cm and \X cm of B] (E) {E};
\draw (A)--(B)--(E);
%
% the RHS branch
\node[below right=\Y cm and \X cm of A] (C) {C};
\node[below right=\Y cm and \X cm of C] (H) {H};
\draw (A)--(C)--(H);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Changing the variables `\X` and `\Y` in the preamble, one can simply control the angle of your branches.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Within forest, there are plenty of options, such as

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        draw
    }
    [A
       [B
       [E]
       [,phantom]
       [,phantom]
       ]
       [C
       [,phantom]
       [,phantom]
       [H]
       ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={
        circle,
        draw
    }
    [A
       [B,grow=-110
       [E]
       ]
       [C,grow=-70
       [H]
       ]
    ]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can implement it:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% Nodes
\node[circle, draw=black] (a) at (0,0) {$A$};
\node[circle, draw=black, below left = of a] (b) {$B$};
\node[circle, draw=black, below right = of a] (c) {$C$};
\node[circle, draw=black, below left = of b] (d) {$D$};
\node[circle, draw=black, below right = of c] (e) {$E$};
% Draw
\draw[black] (a) -- (b);
\draw[black] (a) -- (c);
\draw[black] (b) -- (d);
\draw[black] (c) -- (e);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Romain